# Values not inserting into SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have been working on a website that has two tables, a `user table` and a `content table`. I have no problems inserting new users into the user table via a registration form. However, when I `submit` my `content` values through the form the info `is not being inserted into the database`. All I did was copy the code I used to insert new users into the `users table` and change the SQL statement and variables to be in accordance with my content table.

When I check phpmyadmin, the values aren't being entered into the table so something is wrong but I'm not sure what it is.

All I have on my content table (cheathamContent) are:
id
movie VARCHAR
review VARCHAR

```
<?php
    include_once "header.inc.php";
    //set initial variables
    $showform = 1;  // show form is true
    $errormsg = 0;
    $errormovie = "";
    $errorreview = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        //create variables to store data from form - we never use POST directly w/ 
        //user input
        /* ****** NEW - CHANGED USERNAME TO LOWERCASE ****** */
        $formdata['movie'] = trim($_POST['movie']);
        $formdata['review'] = trim($_POST['review']);

        //check for empty fields
        if (empty($formdata['movie'])) {
            $errorcat = "The movie title is required.";
            $errormsg = 1;
        }
        if (empty($formdata['review'])) {
            $errorcat = "The review field is empty.";
            $errormsg = 1;
        }
        if($errormsg == 1)
        {
            echo "<p class='error'>Please correct the errors and submit again.</p>";
        } else{
            try{
                //query the data
                $sql = "INSERT INTO cheathamContent (movie, review) 
                  VALUES (:movie, :review) ";
                //prepares a statement for execution
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                //binds the actual value of $_GET['ID'] to
                $stmt->bindValue(':movie', $formdata['movie']);
                $stmt->bindValue(':review', $formdata['review']);
                //executes a prepared statement
                $stmt->execute();
                //hide the form
                $showform =0;
                //provide useful confirmation to user
                echo "<p>Thanks for your review!</p>";
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die( $e->getMessage() );
            }
        } // else errormsg
    }//submit
    if($showform == 1){
    ?>
        <form name="addreview" id="addreview" method="post" action="viewlist.php">
            <table class="register">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="movie">Movie Name: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="movie" id="movie" type="text"placeholder="Movie Title" value="<?php if(isset($formdata['movie'])){ echo $formdata['movie'];}?>" /><span class="error">* <?php if(isset($errormovie)){echo $errormovie;}?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="review">Review: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input name="review" id="review" type="text" placeholder="Review" value="<?php if(isset($formdata['review'])){ echo $formdata['review'];}?>" /><span class="error">* <?php if(isset($errorreview)){echo $errorreview;}?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="submit">Submit: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <?php
    }//end showform
    include_once "footer.inc.php";
?>
```

Comment: Add some code to verify the result of the execution and possible error cause if the insert fails

Comment: where is your DB connection code?

Comment: i have it included in my header

Comment: any message for `$e->getMessage()`?

Comment: try and print the contents of `$formdata` before you insert it and see if it returns any value. Also, add `die` after printing so that it will stop there